# CefSharp WinForms 101 read the cookies from browser -- VisitAllCookies now undefined

Tags: c#, cefsharp

This code that worked perfectly on these following version of cefsharp.

cef.redist.x86     v3.2171.2069

CefSharp.Common   v39.0.0

CefSharp.Winforms v39.0.0

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser Chromebrowser;
public void InitializeChromium()
{
    CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
    settings.CachePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\tmp";
    Cef.Initialize(settings);
    Chromebrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://example.com/auth/login");
    panel1.Controls.Add(Chromebrowser);
    Chromebrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;          
}

private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeChromium();
    Chromebrowser.TitleChanged += Chromebrowser_TitleChanged;
}

private void Chromebrowser_TitleChanged(object sender, TitleChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Title);
                Chromebrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByName(\"email\")[0].value = \""+Username+ "\";document.getElementById(\"password\").value = \""+Password+"\"");
    if (Chromebrowser.Address == "https://example.com/loggedin")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Login successful");
        Cef.VisitAllCookies(new webview_cookies(ks2));
        // this line now throws error because 'Cef' does not contain a definition for 'VisitAllCookies'
        // Apparently it seems the newest version of of Cefsharp.code does not have inbuilt VisitAllCookies.
                        
           
        }
    }
}  

class CookieMonster : ICookieVisitor
{
    readonly List<Tuple<string, string>> cookies = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    readonly Action<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>> useAllCookies;

    public CookieMonster(Action<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>> useAllCookies)
    {
        this.useAllCookies = useAllCookies;
    }

    public bool Visit(System.Net.Cookie cookie, int count, int total, ref bool deleteCookie)
    {
        cookies.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(cookie.Name, cookie.Value));
        if (count == total - 1)
            useAllCookies(cookies);
        return true;
    }
}

class webview_cookies : ICookieVisitor
{
    Iamclass ks2;    
    public webview_cookies(Iamclass ks)
    {
        ks2 = ks;
    }
    public bool Visit(Cookie cookie, int count, int total, ref bool deleteCookie)
    {
        //here you can store the cookie value to a static class
        Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + " =  " + cookie.Value);            
            if (cookie.Name == "_ga")
                ks2._ga = cookie.Value;
            if (cookie.Name == "client")
                ks2._client = cookie.Value;            
            if (cookie.Name == "PHPSESSID")
            {
                ks2.PHPSESSID = cookie.Value;
                ks2.logged = true;
            }                
        return true;
    }
}
```

It worked for time being until I recently upgraded chromium browser to the latest. Any experienced professional here using the latest version and know anything about reading cookie method appreciated.

The are currently installed latest version of cefsharp is

cef.redist.x86    v101.0.15

CefSharp.Common   v101.0.150

CefSharp.Winforms  v101.0.150

The new version of cesharp have IcookieManager now I am trying to find how to use the icookiemanager to read the cookies.

This is from latest CefSharp.core

```
  // Summary:
    //     Returns the global cookie manager. By default data will be stored at CefSettings.CachePath
    //     if specified or in memory otherwise. Using this method is equivalent to calling
    //     Cef.GetGlobalRequestContext().GetCookieManager() The cookie managers storage
    //     is created in an async fashion, whilst this method may return a cookie manager
    //     instance, there may be a short delay before you can Get/Write cookies. To be
    //     sure the cookie manager has been initialized use one of the following - Access
    //     the ICookieManager after ICompletionCallback.OnComplete has been called - Access
    //     the ICookieManager instance in IBrowserProcessHandler.OnContextInitialized. -
    //     Use the ChromiumWebBrowser BrowserInitialized (OffScreen) or IsBrowserInitializedChanged
    //     (WinForms/WPF) events.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   callback:
    //     If non-NULL it will be executed asynchronously on the CEF UI thread after the
    //     manager's storage has been initialized.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A the global cookie manager or null if the RequestContext has not yet been initialized.
    public static ICookieManager GetGlobalCookieManager(ICompletionCallback callback = null);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the Global Request Context. Make sure to Dispose of this object when finished.
    //     The earlier possible place to access the IRequestContext is in IBrowserProcessHandler.OnContextInitialized.
    //     Alternative use the ChromiumWebBrowser BrowserInitialized (OffScreen) or IsBrowserInitializedChanged
    //     (WinForms/WPF) events.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     Returns the global request context or null if the RequestContext has not been
    //     initialized yet.
```

'

Comment: You might get a better answer if you [edit]ed your question to show us the previous version of CEFSharp / Chromium: the version you know worked.

Comment: Get the cookie manager then call the relevant method. There are some async examples at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/1a162573fca74426c1a55b60dc7cb000c6447969/CefSharp.Example/Handlers/BrowserProcessHandler.cs#L26 You can still use the visitor if that works for you.

Comment: @amaitland Hi, thanks for the link. My code is fixed by changing just one line.

Comment: @O.Jones Code fixed by modifying one line.

Comment: There is also https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#cookie-manager as a reference to others

Answer (score 1):

```
Cef.VisitAllCookies(new webview_cookies(ks2));
```

Instead of calling directly from Cef.xxx called by GetGlobalCookieManager().

```
CefSharp.Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager().VisitAllCookies(new webview_cookies(ks2));
```

Now the code works fine. Additionally Visual Studio suggested me to generation IDispoable. I clicked OK and the following code automatically added to webview_cookies class.

```
class webview_cookies : ICookieVisitor
{
    Kolotibablo ks2;

    public webview_cookies(Kolotibablo ks)
    {
        ks2 = ks;
    }
    public bool Visit(Cookie cookie, int count, int total, ref bool deleteCookie)
    {
        //here you can store the cookie value to a static class

        Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + " =  " + cookie.Value);

        if (cookie.Name == "_ga")
            ks2._ga = cookie.Value;
        if (cookie.Name == "client")
            ks2._client = cookie.Value;
        if (cookie.Name == "PHPSESSID")
        {
            ks2.PHPSESSID = cookie.Value;
            ks2.logged = true;
        }
        if (cookie.Name == "counter_user_id")
            ks2._counter_user_id = cookie.Value;


        return true;
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~webview_cookies()
    // {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion



}
```

Thank you for ming526197zhang user on github. I got the hint on how to use GetGlobalcookieManager from his code.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1427

I put the sample code on github which is generic and simple. Hope it helps someone like me in the future.

https://github.com/stackunderflow2022/cfsharpcookie2022/blob/main/WindowsFormsApp1/Form1.cs

Comment: Yeah VS is really good about suggesting interfaces to implement to make classes tie in nicely to the framework.